# How do I migrate a module to remove a custom `res.config.settings` field?

Tags: module, migration, odoo, data-migration

Suppose I have a module which defines some custom `res.config.settings` fields like so:

```py
from odoo import models, fields

class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"

    custom_field = fields.Char(config_parameter="custom.field")
    some_other_custom_field = fields.Char(config_parameter="some.other.custom.field")
```

And then in my XML I have something like this:

```xml
<odoo>
    <record id="custom_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">custom.settings.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="custom_base_settings_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <div data-string="custom" position="inside">
                <h2>Custom</h2>
                <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 o_setting_box">
                        <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                            <label for="custom_field"/>
                            <div class="text-muted">Description...</div>
                            <div class="content-group">
                                <div class="mt16">
                                    <field name="custom_field"
                                    placeholder="Placeholder..."/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                            <label for="some_other_custom_field"/>
                            <div class="text-muted">Description...</div>
                            <div class="content-group">
                                <div class="mt16">
                                    <field name="some_other_custom_field"
                                    placeholder="Placeholder..."/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Suppose that now later I've implemented some new functionality elsewhere that eliminates my need for `custom_field`. As such, I'd like to remove it entirely. However, as you can see, the `custom_settings_view_form` also includes `some_other_custom_field`, which I need to keep. This means that my options are limited:

- I cannot just remove the `ir.ui.view` record, because then I would lose the UI for `some_other_custom_field`.
- I also cannot just uninstall and then install the module again, because it would result in data loss elsewhere.

So specifically I want to remove the following line from my model:

```py
custom_field = fields.Char(config_parameter="custom.field")
```

And the following block from my XML:

```xml
<div class="o_setting_right_pane">
    <label for="custom_field"/>
    <div class="text-muted">Description...</div>
    <div class="content-group">
        <div class="mt16">
            <field name="custom_field"
            placeholder="Placeholder..."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I remove that code and then run my Odoo server again with `-u <name_of_containing_module>`, I get the following error:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating view

Field `custom_field` does not exist

Error context:
View `custom.settings.view.form`
[view_id: <id>, xml_id: <name_of_containing_module>.custom_settings_view_form, model: res.config.settings, parent_id: <parent_id>]
...
```

I just learned that I can create scripts at `<module_root>/migrations/<version>/` to help with this sort of situation, but I have no idea what I would need to put in my migration script to deal with this issue. How can I remove fields and modify views in a module without causing errors and without requiring that the module be reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this steps:

1. Remove `custom_field` from XML view and change the actual id
   `custom_settings_view_form`.
2. Update your module, that shouldn't produce any error and you won't see `custom_field` any more.

At this moment you could deside ignore `custom_field`, nothing will happend. Any way if you are a person that don't like death code inside his project like me, you can continue with the next steps.

4. Remove `custom_field` definition for `.py` file.
5. Update your module.

If you have the same error reported, you sould execute the 3.1 step bellow.

3.1. Clean the database data for `custom_field`. By SQL. Continue with 4 and 5 steps.

Please share your comments of the execution of these steps.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: I ended up doing this (I updated the XML and upgraded the module, then updated the Python and upgraded the module again) but the problem is that for an addon I've released to customers this pattern is unacceptable because I need to be able to release a new version which will not cause errors when customers upgrade the addon. I can't just expect customers to go into the addon and manually edit source code. Therefore, as I mentioned in the question, I am looking to learn what Odoo **migration script** would allow me to enable a seamless one-click upgrade process.